# deploy DLL in Visual Fox Pro application

Tags: c#, .net, visual-foxpro

i have a visual fox pro 9 application that i need to connect it to a .net 3.5 dll I am not being able to add it in the project.

Can anyone help me with this..

Thank you

Comment: As far as I know, Fox Pro is not a .NET and therefore it can not connect directly to .NET libraries. It would be nice if you cloud write more details. Are you the developer of the Fox Pro application? Are you the developer of the .NET library? Can you make some changes in one or another application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VFP cannot use .NET assemblies directly.  They can use them through COM, web services, or other interop layers.

There are third-party libraries out there that act as a "bridge" between VFP and .NET by exposing the .NET types through late-bound calls (e.g. `CreateInstance("MyDotNetObject")`) but there is no "native" support for .NET within VFP.

If you want to roll your own bridge one straightforward way would be:

- Create a .NET library that references the other .NET library
- Add classes that are COM-visible and pass-through the calls to the other library
- Create instances of the interop class(es) by using `CreateObject` in VFP.

You can read [this article](http://www.codemag.com/Article/0404072) for more information, or just search for "VFP COM interop" to find other examples.

Comment: The original poster might find https://west-wind.com/wwDotnetBridge.aspx helpful here.